# Python date rollover

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to send a file after a loop completes while inside an endless loop.  Everything works except the trigger for sending the file.  How can I check if midnight passed when I was in the loop?

```
from datetime import date    

while(True):

    stamp = date.today()

    for site in siteList:
        # Long series of url requests and data processing

    check = date.today()

    if stamp != check: # <--- This doesn't work I don't know why
        # Send today's file
```

Comment: import date? what is that? your own module? what does date.today() return?

Comment: Sanity check: do you _have_ to instantiate `check` inside the infinite loop? Can't you just figure out what day it is once?

Comment: woops your right it's datetime's date that was a typing error, it's right in the code.

Comment: I want it to do something once a day after the inner loop finishes, how it's done doesn't matter.

Comment: How, exactly, is your code not working?  Is the trigger executing when it shouldn't, or is it failing to execute when it should?

Comment: The trigger doesn't execute

Comment: The code definitely works as expected, but what you are failing to see is that stamp will always equal check because both stamp = date.today() and check = date.today() will always change at same time to the new date after midnight.

Comment: If on Linux why not set up a cron job to call script once per day?  If on Windows schedule a task to call.

Comment: Was considering a cron job but I need to execute after a completion of the inner loop and that can take hours.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your code should work.  Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

Have you tried printing `stamp` and `check` so you can see what values are being used?

Is your timezone set properly?

Comment: timezone is UTC, stamp is used as timestamp and outputs as expected.  Check always equals stamp even though it's assigned after the hours long loop.

Comment: When you print `stamp` and `check` they are the same?  Are they both the earlier date, or the later date?  And are you printing them as soon as they are assigned, or later on?

Answer (score 0):

This is fragile and is going to cause you problems.  The only way this will ever fire is if your processing *actually* spans midnight.  This is because you update your check date every loop as well as your original date.

If you are committed to this, set the value of stamp *outside* the loop, and then update it inside your if block so that your send file function will always fire once per day.

However, starting a script on a machine and leaving it running for a long period of time with no supervision is just going to lead to heartache.  You need some kind of job processor- I either have my webapp's work queue fire the periodic task, or if it is really external I have my Jenkins server run it- in either case I can look somewhere and see when things ran last and get notified if something goes wrong.

Comment: The stamp is used to mark a file, the check is to see if it's time to send that file off.  This is for an AWS instance and has alarms associated with it.

Comment: Right- so if the inner loop takes 4 hours, you want the inner loop to execute 6 times with _different_ values for `stamp` each time... but to only ship one of those to the target?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if midnight passed when I was in the loop?

Your code already does it if you mean the internal loop: `date.today()` returns only the date i.e., unless the day ends during the inner loop; `stamp` and `check` are always equal.

If you meant the outer loop then move `stamp = date.today()` outside of the outer loop and update `stamp` only on if the trigger is executed i.e., if `stamp != check`. btw, you should use a better names such as `last_date` and `today`. You could set `last_date = None` initially, to trigger the execution on the first pass.

> I want it to do something once a day after the inner loop finishes

```
from datetime import date

last_date = None
while True: # outer loop
   for site in siteList: # inner loop
       "hours long computations here"
   today = date.today()
   if last_date is None or last_date < today:
       last_date = today # jobs are executed on different days
       "send today's file here"
```

In general, it is more flexible to separate the code that schedules a task from the code that defines the task itself e.g., you could create a cron job, to run something once a day. You could use locks, to wait for the inner loop to finish and to avoid running multiple jobs in parallel ([cron doesn't protect against it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58481/1321)). Two jobs may happen on the same day if the previous job took more than a day.